# Reopen the prolog program after every edit for the code

Tags: swi-prolog

Why should i halt the prolog program and run it again when i edit the code??
Is there any way to recompile without halting the program and reopen.
Note I'm using swi 5.8.3 for windows.

Answer (score 0):

consult the help:

```
apropos(load_files).
```

There are many other predicates that may help. Maybe you need to unload the file before reloading - so the the knowledge gets overwritten.